# How to calculate timezone differences

Tags: go, timezone

I think it best to start with the goal:

```
NSYE opens at 09:30:00  - It opens in X minutes/It closes in Y minutes.
LSE opens at 08:00:00 GMT - It opens in X minutes/It closes in Y minutes.
```

Current code:

```golang
type StockExchanges map[string]string

func showOpeningTime() {
    for stockExchanges, stockExchange := range map[string]StockExchanges{
        "NYSE": {
            "open": "09:30:00",
            "close": "16:00:00",
            "location": "America/New_York",
        },
        "LSE": {
            "open": "08:00:00",
            "close": "16:00:00",
            "location": "Europe/London",
        },
    } {
        currentTime, err := TimeIn(time.Now(), stockExchange)
        if err == nil {
          ///////CODE HERE//////
        } else {
            fmt.Println(stockExchange, "<time unknown>")
        }
    }
    return
}

func TimeIn(t time.Time, stockExchanges StockExchanges) (time.Time, error) {
    loc, err := time.LoadLocation(stockExchanges["location"])
    if err == nil {
        t = t.In(loc)
    }
    return t, err
}
```

So with the users `currentTime` in their timezone, I want to see how long it will be before opening time for all stockexchanges.

For example: assuming you are in GMT, the NYSE isn't open until `14:30:00 GMT`, so lets say the current time is `14:29:00 gmt`, I would like the output to be:

```
NSYE opens at 09:30:00  - It opens in 00:01:00 minutes.
LSE opens at 08:00:00 GMT - It is currently open.
```

I get the users timeszone correctly, and it returns a time object which includes the offset.
My solution can be changed completely and entirely.

Comment: In the JSON, the formatting of open/close times is different across stock exchanges. NYSE's object contains seconds, whereas that of LSE does not. Is this intentional?

Comment: Apologies, a typo on my part. I will update now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  convert to today/tomo  date and compare with current time

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

type StockExchanges map[string]string

func showOpeningTime() {
    for stockExchanges, stockExchange := range map[string]StockExchanges{
        "NYSE": {
            "open": "09:30:00",
            "close": "16:00:00",
            "location": "America/New_York",
        },
        "LSE": {
            "open": "08:00:00",
            "close": "16:00:00",
            "location": "Europe/London",
        },
    } {
        currentTime, err := TimeIn(time.Now(), stockExchange)
        if err == nil {
            ///////CODE HERE//////
            hour, min, sec := getTime(stockExchange["open"])
            TodaysStartTime := time.Date( currentTime.Year() ,currentTime.Month(),currentTime.Day() ,
                hour,min,sec,0,currentTime.Location())
            hour, min, sec = getTime(stockExchange["close"])
            TodaysEndTime := time.Date( currentTime.Year() ,currentTime.Month(),currentTime.Day() ,
                hour,min,sec,0,currentTime.Location())
            if currentTime.Before(TodaysStartTime) {
                // NSYE opens at 09:30:00  - It opens in 00:01:00 minutes.
                fmt.Println(stockExchanges + " opens at  ",stockExchange["open"] ," - It opens in  ", TodaysStartTime.Sub(currentTime).String()   )
            }else if currentTime.Before(TodaysEndTime)  {
                //opens at 08:00:00 GMT - It is currently open.
                fmt.Println(stockExchanges + " opens at  ",stockExchange["open"] , " It is currently open" )
            }else {
                  // opens tomo
                hour, min, sec = getTime(stockExchange["open"])
                tomo := currentTime.Add(24 * time.Hour)
                TomoStartTime := time.Date( tomo.Year() ,tomo.Month(),tomo.Day() ,
                    hour,min,sec,0,currentTime.Location())
                // NSYE opens at 09:30:00  - It opens in 00:01:00 minutes.
                fmt.Println(stockExchanges + " opens at  ",stockExchange["open"] ," - It opens in  ", TomoStartTime.Sub(currentTime).String()   )
            }
        } else {
            fmt.Println(stockExchange, "<time unknown>")
        }
    }
    return
}

func TimeIn(t time.Time, stockExchanges StockExchanges) (time.Time, error) {
    loc, err := time.LoadLocation(stockExchanges["location"])
    if err == nil {
        t = t.In(loc)
    }
    return t, err
}

func getTime(time string) (int,int,int){
    t:= strings.Split(time,":")
    hour ,_ := strconv.ParseInt(t[0],10,64)
    min ,_ := strconv.ParseInt(t[1],10,64)
    sec ,_ := strconv.ParseInt(t[2],10,64)
    return int(hour),int(min),int(sec)
}


func main () {

    showOpeningTime()
}
```

check in the [go  playground](https://play.golang.org/p/C92CzA-Nf05)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and it makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the effort put in. If you were to do a similar task, would you do it in this kind of way? Or is there a more "Go" style way of achieving the same thing that you know of that I probably don't? Thanks!

Comment: @intRG this should be fine